# Saving complex object in Swift using NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, persistence, nsuserdefaults

I want to save my game data using NSUserDefaults which seems the easiest way.

The objects I want to save are really complex, meaning they have a bunch of subclasses which have a bunch of subclasses etc. As far as I am aware, NSUserDefaults only stores the primitive data types. Casting the objects to NSData or anything does not work. Implementing the NSCoding protocol is a huge pain with such complex classes.

What is the easiest way to achieve the storing of such objects? Should I use something other than NSUserDefaults?

Comment: Use `sqlite` and store data as a BLOB.

Answer (score 0):

That is not what `NSUserDefaults` is designed for and as you know only a few primitive types are supported.

You need to be professional and do the work, in this case that means implementing `NSCoding` and archiving to a file with `NSArchiver`.